# Bash alternative to trim newline \n and extra white-space

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, kubuntu, text-processing

I am trying to parse a multiline sentence:

```
You have to go tomorrow by
                                        car.
```

As you can see there is a new line + space then "car."

I used this regex:

```
You.have.to.go.tomorrow.by.\n.+
```

It worked great when I used it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but when I used it in bash, it worked for only the first sentence:

```
Parser='You.have.to.go.tomorrow.by.\n.+'
```

Result:

```
You have to go tomorrow by
```

I am using bash, I want the full sentence:

```
"You have to go tomorrow by car."
```

I am using:

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' | grep -oP $parser
```

to delete all HTML tags then grep for the parser.

Comment: How exactly are you using it, and what type of result do you need? Note that many regex tools like `grep` search each line separately, so a pattern that tries to match across multiple lines will not work.

Comment: I am using bash , I want the full sentence : "You have to go tomorrow by car " i am using (sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' | grep -oP $parser ) to delet all html tags then grep for the parser

Comment: `sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g'` will add spaces while `sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g'` will do the same job minus the extra spaces.

Comment: Just a note, you're not using regular expressions in bash. You're using regular expressions in _grep_. The fact you use bash is irrelevant here.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4400820

Answer (score 4):

`-z, --null-data` separates lines with NUL character instead of newline, which makes it possible to match newlines.

```
grep -Pzo \
'You have to go tomorrow by\n\s+car.' text | tr -s '\n ' ' '
```

If you were to do it in pure bash, you would probably need to ANSI-quote your pattern to represent *newline*.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

pattern=$'You have to go tomorrow by\n\s+car.'
[[ $(<text) \
=~ ($pattern) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
```

Assume you intend to clean up only the line you are referring to, then it's possible to combine substitutions. Matching the line containing '*You have to go tomorrow by*' we can then group and run multiple commands with braces `{...}`, separated by semicolons, on this match.

```
sed -rn '/You have to go tomorrow by/{N; s/\n//; s/ {2,}/ /; s/<[^>]+>//g;p}' text
```

- `N` Read the next line and add it to the pattern space.
- `s` substitute text.
- `g` global, substitute all occurrences in the line.
- `p` print.

Answer (score 3):

#### With `tr`

```
<FileName tr -s '\n' ' '
```

#### With `xargs`

```
<FileName xargs
```

#### Notice

Change `FileName` with the name of the file containing the two lines.

- `<FileName` will read the file and output to STDIN... i.e something like `cat FileName |`.
- `tr -s '\n' ' '` brings the two lines into one line and removes multiple spaces leaving only single spaces.
- `xargs` by default trims newlines and extra white space as part of its job to converts input from STDIN into arguments to a command... i.e. this is how it works to do its job.

You can also pipe the output from `sed` to `tr` like so:

```
<FileName sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | tr -s '\n' ' '
```

or from `sed` to `xargs` like so:

```
<FileName sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g' | xargs
```