# How to find number of unique words in first row using bash command?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to find the number of unique words in my file named cdj.tsv. I can use `head -n 1 cdj.tsv` to get the first line. Now I want number of unique words in this line. How can I get that?
Result of the command `head -n 1 cdj.tsv` looks like:

```
Country China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   China   Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark DenmarkDenmark  Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark DenmarkDenmark  Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark DenmarkDenmark  Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark DenmarkDenmark  Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark Denmark DenmarkDenmark  Denmark
```

So, I want the output to be 3 (for Country, China and Denmark).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### One *simple* way:

- Get the first line from a file with `head -n 1 cdj.tsv` *(You already know that)* or from multiple files by name like this `head -q -n 1 cdj.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv` the [`-q`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/head.1.html) will suppress printing extra headers / file names so that only the lines from the files are printed. You can use [globbing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-globbing-linux/) `*` with input file names as well like this `head -q -n 1 *.tsv` to process all files in the current directory with `.tsv` extension as input.
- Then, [pipe `|`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/#:%7E:text=A%20pipe%20is%20a%20form,program%2Fprocess%20for%20further%20processing.) that to [`tr -s ' ' '\n'`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/tr.1.html) to process the words each on a new line *i.e. one at a time* ... *(notice: [many alternate tools](https://askubuntu.com/a/1323380) can be used to do the same thing in this step even the much less efficient [`xargs -n 1`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/xargs.1.html) and the answer by [@Peter Cordes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409919) in this regard is worth reading.)*
- Then, pipe that to [`sort -u`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/sort.1plan9.html) to sort and print only unique words.
- Then, to get both the words themselves and their count, pipe that to [`tee`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/tee.1plan9.html) with [`wc -l`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/wc.1.html) in a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) syntax `>(wc -l)` and put both in a [subshell](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) syntax `(...)` to group the output like so:

  ```
  head -q -n 1 *.tsv | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort -u | (tee >(wc -l))
  ```
- The result from your example will look like this:

  ```
  China
  Country
  Denmark
  DenmarkDenmark
  4
  ```

#### Another *faster* way with [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/awk.1plan9.html) or [gawk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gawk.1.html):

- Start *a word (field) counter*, set its initial value to `1` like this `i=1`, limit its maximum value to the available number of fields like this `i<=NF` and increment it by `1` with each new field like this `i++` and put all that in an [awk `for` control statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html) syntax like this `for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ )`.
- Then, for each field, check if the line being processed is the first line in the file like this `NR==1` and if that is true check if the current field (word) hasn't occurred before and if true add its reference to an array like this `!seen[$i]++` and print it with `print $i` and put all that in an [awk `if` control statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/If-Statement.html) syntax in an action group `{...}` like this `{ if ( NR==1 && !seen[$i]++ ) print $i }`.
- Then, print the total number of unique words (fields) with `print length(seen)` and put it in a separate action group after the [awk conditional pattern element](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pattern-Overview.html) `END` like this `END { print length(seen) }`.
- Then, Use it on a single input file like so:

  ```
  awk '{ for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { if ( NR==1 && !seen[$i]++ ) print $i }} END { print length(seen) }' cdj.tsv
  ```
- Or use it on multiple input files with `FNR==1` instead of `NR==1` like so:

  ```
  awk '{ for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { if ( FNR==1 && !seen[$i]++ ) print $i }} END { print length(seen) }' *.tsv
  ```
- Or use it on multiple input files with `<(head -q -n 1 *.tsv)` and without `NR==1` or `FNR==1` like so:

  ```
  awk '{ for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { if ( !seen[$i]++ ) print $i }} END { print length(seen) }' <(head -q -n 1 *.tsv)
  ```

Comment: `xargs -n 1` seems an awkward and inefficient way to tokenize a string.  It forks+execs `echo` for every input word, so **it will lose words like `-n` that are options to `/bin/echo`**, as well as being slow for large inputs.  (And yes, I checked with `strace -f xargs -n 1` that it does actually fork/exec, not handling this special case internally).  Your Awk version is much better, just histogramming.  You could also just use `tr`, `sed`, or `awk` to turn whitespace into newlines to feed to `sort -u`.

Comment: @PeterCordes “Awkward” maybe but correct… “it will lose words” can you prove this? “`/bin/echo`” that’s part of how xargs work … `tr`,`sed`, or `awk` or even pure `bash` are possible alternatives but `xargs` comes ready out of the box with not only ability to deal with white space but newlines as well among others and this becomes handy in the case of reading from multiple files above … I agree it is slower this way  but then the faster `awk` method is provided. Diversity is a good thing… letting folks know possible different ways of doing something is good too :)

Comment: Sure, easy to prove: `echo 'foo -n' | xargs -n 1` prints `foo` instead of `foo` / `-n` on my Arch GNU/Linux system (GNU coreutils 9.0, xargs from GNU findutils 4.8.0).  The fact that `/bin/echo` is part of how xargs works if you don't specify a command is exactly why you shouldn't use it this way, at least on GNU systems where `echo` supports some options.

Comment: @PeterCordes This behavior is both expected and wanted. This is what I meant by “among others” in my previous comment:) The OP wants unique **words** …. Need l say more? … Nevertheless, your obsetvation is true.

Comment: It's not robust or efficient, so as a general pattern I'd definitely recommend `echo 'foo -n bar' | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/\n/g'` over it.  There might be other easier-to-remember idioms with other tools, IDK.  The best I can say about `xargs` with echo is that it's at least probably not a security problem because it invokes echo directly, not via a shell.  And `echo -efoo` doesn't work like `echo -e foo` so it doesn't let tricky input get binary data or spaces into the output lines.

Comment: I don't think `xargs -n 1` is a very good trick to teach future readers, since not everyone is dealing with the special case of English words.  If there are `-n` tokens in the input, many people would want to know about them, not silently hide them.

Comment: `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'` also works to squeeze any (optionally repeated) whitespace down to one newline.  Tested with `echo -e 'foo \t  -n \n  bar' | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'` to mix in other whitespace, not just `' '`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Every tool will fail when used for other purposes than what it was designed for … your other examples are ok but you insist on using xargs the wrong way… this doesn’t make sense … you clearly don’t like xargs :)

Comment: You're the one insisting on using `xargs` in a weird way, using its `echo` default to turn it into a string tokenizer with some corner cases for some strings.  And no, I don't like running a whole process for every word of an input file; that's obviously inefficient.  `xargs` wasn't designed to tokenize arbitrary data, only text that you actually want to use as command line arguments.  The `echo` default is I think intended as a debugging feature.

Comment: @PeterCordes Using a graphical desktop environment is inefficient as well … should everyone abandon it?!  … No? Why? Because it’s easy and simple to use … that’s why. … don’t you agree?

Comment: `tr -s` isn't particularly harder, though.  To be fair, I did have to check the man page for the `-s` option and that it does character classes, but that took me about 5 to 10 seconds.  Part of the goal when writing something to go in a script is to make it robust.  `xargs -n 1` isn't robust, so it would need to have major convenience advantages to be worth remembering for one-off use-cases when it can work.  It's not that major, IMO, and feels convoluted and weird to use it for string processing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Among other things, and out of the box, xargs will not pass empty new lines as arguments while all your provided alternative examples will … bottomline, every tool has its pros and cons and the user should weigh these and decide efficiency / simplicity … and sometimes we mention both, objectively, in our answers without imposing our own opinions (sometimes)

Comment: I tested my `tr` suggestion with `echo -e 'foo \t  -n \n\n \n  bar\n\nbaz' | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'`.  I don't get any empty lines because `-s` squeezes any number of whitespace characters down to one newline.  Same for my `sed` suggestion, which uses `+` for the same reason.  So I'm not sure what problem you're pointing out, please show an example if I'm missing something.  None of them pass any of the input strings as actual command line args to anything, so they also don't leak information to other users via `ps auxw`.

Comment: @PeterCordes what if one new line has a space before the first word? Do you get empty new line passed as argument?

Comment: Ah yes, leading whitespace does lead to an empty line in the output, which is part of what gets sorted and counted.  Good point, thanks.  But at no point is it an "argument" to anything.  It's only data being piped around.

Comment: @PeterCordes “Not an argument” true … Just figuratively speaking :)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'undef %c; grep($c{$_}++,split); print join(" ",scalar(%c),keys %c),"\n"'

4 Country China DenmarkDenmark Denmark
```

Comment: Thanks, user10489. I have multiple files. How can I specify them as input for this command?

Comment: That wasn't in your question, so this doesn't handle that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 head -q -n 1 *.tsv | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | sort -u | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

`tr -s characters \n` is a good way to split on whitespace, into separate lines.  Any number of whitespace characters are "squeezed" (`tr -s`) down to one newline.

If you also want to remove leading whitespace (before the first word), you can use `sed` with two separate `-e` operations, one for that and one to squeeze later whitespace.  `-E` is extended regex

```
... | sed -E -e 's/^[[::space:]]+// -e 's/[[:space:]]+/\n/g' | ...
```

Alternatively to using `tee` to the terminal (which interferes with redirecting the whole thing to a file), [@Raffa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409772/116941) suggests `| (tee >(wc -l))` process substitution.  (Not sure why `tee` itself has to be in a subshell, though.)

---

A more efficient version would just histogram in `awk` or `perl` instead of piping through multiple processes to sort-unique and then count.  Two other answers show ways to do that.

---

Another part of Raffa's answer is not a good suggestion for general use, though.  `xargs -n 1` (using its default command of `echo`) works as an alternative to `tr` for some cases, but is much slower (fork/exec of a whole process for every word).

Worse, GNU `echo` eats `-n` and `-e` so it's not robust if your text could contain those "words".  For example,

```
echo -e 'foo \t  -n \n\n bar\n\n\nbaz' |  tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | sort -u | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
bar
baz
foo
-n
4
```

```
# this version loses the -n
echo -e 'foo \t  -n \n\n bar\n\n\nbaz' |  xargs -n 1 | sort -u | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
bar
baz
foo
3
```

The `xargs -n 1` hack also exposes your data to other users as command line args, which they could see via `ps auxw` if they ran it at just the right time.  (e.g. in a loop, or via something watching `/proc` to grab the command line args of new PIDs.)

If you don't care about efficiency for small data sets and find it easier to type for interactive use, you can use it if you want, but it's a weird abuse of `xargs`'s debug feature of defaulting to `echo` instead of a meaningful command.  It's definitely not something you'd want to put in a script; if you're going to take the time to write a script, use something robust and efficient if it only takes an extra couple seconds to type or remind yourself of what a man page says.

It does have one upside of ignoring leading whitespace.

Comment: The sub-shell at the end is to group both words and their count in case of redirecting to a file … **+1** :).